# android studio webview применить javascript по ссылке

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

такой вопрос как применить java script по ссылке к webview https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/lmibwymtkebspij/background.js
после полной загрузки страницы фон должен стать зеленым
вот пример кода как загружаю страницу

```
 webView = findViewById(R.id.Web);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
```

заранее  благодарен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

может кому пригодится
грузим текст скрипта в переменную script используя get запрос на линк адреса скрипта
как то так :

```
  @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... path) {
        try {
            content = getContent(path[0]);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            content = ex.getMessage();
        }

        return content;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String content) {
        scriptbg = content;

        Log.d("debug", scriptbg);

    }

    public String getContent(String path) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(path);
            HttpsURLConnection c = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setReadTimeout(10000);
            c.connect();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buf.append(line + "\n");
            }
            return (buf.toString());
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

далее применяем скрипт к нашему webView  при полной загрузке страницы вот так :

```
     public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + Script);
            Log.d("debug", "finish");
        }
```